# Locating Xrite ColorChecker samples in image

Tags: ios, xamarin, computer-vision

I am trying to perform color adjustments in a photo taking mobile app using a Xrite ColorChecker and for that I am trying to come up with a way to locate the color samples on the checker in the view.

I assume

- User has placed the ColorChecker in the camera view
- The position can be arbitrary and can also be in any orientation or even skewed
- App should ideally find the color checker in the camera view automatically, or less ideally with the help of the user (tapping anywhere within the ColorChecker)
- The lighting conditions may not be ideal, so the less dependent the algorithm is on the actual colors, the better

This is how the ColorChecker looks. I am interested specifically in the samples in right half of the device.

[image: Xrite ColorChecker]

The app is targeting iOS 11 and is built in Xamarin.iOS and C#.

### What I have tried already

My first idea was to utilize built in augmented reality capabilities in iOS to identify the rectangle in scene, but I found out that this will not work as the device is not regular shaped and the available methods have hard time locating it. I also learned it is possible to train a machine learning model to answer the question of whether ColorChecker is in the current screen, but still will not answer the question of where the individual color samples are and how is the device oriented.

I have also found [**CCFind** algorithm](http://issl.udayton.edu/index.php/research/ccfind/) using MATLAB, which does find ColorChecker given a photo, but is not fast enough even on powerful PC to be usable as a real-time solution and also MATLAB cannot be ported to iOS, so I tried rewriting the code to OpenCV + C++, which was tedious and I couldn't finish it successfully in almost a month of work.

I am open to any suggestions or tips on how to approach this problem, as I am not very knowledgeable in computer vision area and don't really know where to start.

Comment: I did a “similar” project, not using a Xrite, but it was in the "Macbeth chart" color calibration category. So the two core goals were to find the Macbeth chart colors and apply a color correction in realtime for previewing (and also saving the original raw camera data without any color space applied but that is another story).

Comment: Using CIFilters, some stock and some custom written, I would break the video stream into smaller blocks (chopping-based CIFilters), basically a scanning system, top-left to bottom right. Using a CILineOverlay-style custom filter to simplify the image to find rectangles (skewed or not), check the CIFilter-based histograms to determine if all/some of Macbeth chart colors were found in that rectangle. If so skew correct the rectangle to determine how alter the real-time crop if needed until CIFilter color histogram contains “hits” on all (most) the chart colors within a rectangle.

Comment: Since a Macbeth chart (Xrite or not) contains their chip colors in a pre-determined pattern, it is really easy at that point to obtain each color regardless of orientation and produce the macbeth synthetic ones and thus a CIImage is produced that contains the iOS camera imaged color vs. the synthetic one (this was saved for future reference for post-production usage). A CIFilter color matrix was now apply to the stream and a side-by-side preview output was produced for lighting analysis. Thus the lighting director/gaffer/bestboy could tweak the scene/set in real-time.

Comment: The analysis phase was amazing fast on the latest-gen iPhones and since CIIFilters can be chained and their GPU kernel pre-compiled real-time finding of the color chart only took a second or so before the color-corrected preview was displayed. Of course writing the custom GLSL CIFilters was core to this type of image workflow. The ML approach would be really cool, but in this case I'm not sure the training cost/time is worth it just to find a color chart, but to recommend lighting changes after the color calibration matrix was calculated would be some really good stuff ;-) 

Comment: Thank you very very much for your suggestion @SushiHangover :-) . I will check `CIFilters`, this sounds very promising :-) !